# SASS compass compiler choking on multiple assignment @each loop

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass, precompiler

The following is an example from the [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-multi-assign):

```
@each $animal, $color, $cursor in (puma, black, default),
    (sea-slug, blue, pointer),
    (egret, white, move) {
  .#{$animal}-icon {
     background-image: url('/images/#{$animal}.png');
     border: 2px solid $color;
     cursor: $cursor;
   }
}
```

For some reason, it throws the following error:

> error sass/screen.scss (Line 8: Invalid CSS after "  @each $animal": expected "in", was ", $color, $curs...")

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling ruby/sass/compass to no avail. What gives? Here are the versions I have:

- SASS 3.2.19
- Compass 0.12.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like multiple assignment is SASS 3.3 feature. Maybe [this](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass/issues/263) will help.

Comment: That makes sense. Everytime I ran "gem install compass" it automatically installed SASS 3.2.19.